# I'm doing a control flow lab and i'm having problems making it work. I keep getting finalPrice is not defined

Tags: javascript, control-flow

I'm doing a control flow lab and can't get my code to work.  Says finalPrice not defined. I'm sure i'm missing something simple.

Instructions

> You will need to write an algorithm in code that represents the following set of rules for determining the price of a package.
>
> If the weight of a package is less than 3lbs, the cost of sending the package is $5. Otherwise, the package costs $1.79 per pound. If the sender has a membership with Brooklyn Shipping Solutions, they receive a 10% discount on packages that are less than 10lbs, and a 12% discount on all other packages. Regardless of their membership, if the package is to be delivered on a holiday, the total cost is increased by $5.
>
> Once you have determined the costs above, you should print (i.e. console.log()) a "receipt" for the customer that includes the customer's name, final price, and the package description. For example, your receipt may look like this:
>
> Jasmin Merrill - $X.XX
> Package Description: <DESCRIPTION>
> Additionally, if either packageDescription or packageSender is empty, you should console.log() the following text.
>
> A package description and sender is required!

```
    // Leave these values the same throughout.
    const minimumPriceInCents = 500;
    const priceInCentsPerPound = 179;

    // Change the values of these variables to test out your code.
    const packageDescription = 'Box';
    const packageSender = 'Jimmy';
    const packageWeightInPounds = 2;
    const hasMembership = false;
    const isHolidayDelivery = false;

    // Write your algorithm below!

    let shippingCost = (packageWeightInPounds * priceInCentsPerPound) / 100;

    let minimumPriceInDollars = minimumPriceInCents / 100;

    let finalPrice = 0;

    if (
        isHolidayDelivery === true &&
        hasMembership === true &&
        packageWeightInPounds < 3
    ) {
        let finalPrice = (minimumPriceInDollars * 0.9 + 5);
        console.log(`${packageSender} - $${finaPrice}`);
        console.log(`Package Description: ${packageDescription}`);
    } else if (
        isHolidayDelivery === true &&
        hasMembership === true &&
        packageWeightInPounds >= 10
    ) {
        finalPrice = (minimumPriceInDollars * 0.88 + 5);
        console.log(`${packageSender} - $${finaPrice}`);
        console.log(`Package Description: ${packageDescription}`);
    } else if (
        isHolidayDelivery === false &&
        hasMembership === true &&
        packageWeightInPounds >= 10
    ) {
        finalPrice = (minimumPriceInDollars * 0.88);
        console.log(`${packageSender} - $${finaPrice}`);
        console.log(`Package Description: ${packageDescription}`);
    }
    if (
        isHolidayDelivery === false &&
        hasMembership === true &&
        packageWeightInPounds < 3
    ) {
        finalPrice = (minimumPriceInDollars * 0.9);
        console.log(`${packageSender} - $${finaPrice}`);
        console.log(`Package Description: ${packageDescription}`);
    } else if (
        isHolidayDelivery === false &&
        hasMembership === false &&
        packageWeightInPounds < 3
    ) {
        finalPrice = (minimumPriceInDollars);
        console.log(`${packageSender} - $${finaPrice}`);
        console.log(`Package Description: ${packageDescription}`);
    } else if (
        isHolidayDelivery === true &&
        hasMembership === false &&
        packageWeightInPounds < 3
    ) {
        finalPrice = (minimumPriceInDollars + 5);
        console.log(`${packageSender} - $${finaPrice}`);
        console.log(`Package Description: ${packageDescription}`);
    } else if (isHolidayDelivery === false && hasMembership === false) {
        finalPrice = (minimumPriceInDollars);
        console.log(`${packageSender} - $${finaPrice}`);
        console.log(`Package Description: ${packageDescription}`);
    } else console.log('A package description and sender is required!');
```

Comment: You're declaring `let finalPrice` in multiple scopes. Just declare it once and overwrite it along the way.
Another piece of advice, do one check at a time and add to the total cost rather tan try to figure out the total cost in one go. It will clean up your code.

Comment: Thanks so much.   I'm struggling a bit learning coding for the 1st time.